# SRV from UAV on the same texture in directx

Tags: c++, directx, directx11

I'm programming gpgpu raymarching (volumetric raytracing) in directx11. I succesfully perform compute shader and save raymarched volume data to texture. Then i want to use same texture as SRV in normal graphic pipeline. But it doesnt work, texture is not visible.

Texture is ok, when i save it file it is what i expect. Texture rendering is ok too, when i render another SRV, it is ok. So problem is only in UAV->SRV. I also triple checked if pointers are ok. Please help, i'm getting mad about this.

Here is some code:

```
//before dispatch
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
ZeroMemory( &textureDesc, sizeof( textureDesc ) );
textureDesc.Width = xr;
textureDesc.Height = yr;
textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE ;
textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
D3D->CreateTexture2D( &textureDesc, NULL, &pTexture );

D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC viewDescUAV;
ZeroMemory( &viewDescUAV, sizeof( viewDescUAV ) );
viewDescUAV.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
viewDescUAV.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
viewDescUAV.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
D3DD->CreateUnorderedAccessView( pTexture, &viewDescUAV, &pTextureUAV );

//the getSRV function after dispatch.
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc ;
ZeroMemory( &srvDesc, sizeof( srvDesc ) );
srvDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
D3DD->CreateShaderResourceView( pTexture, &srvDesc, &pTextureSRV);
```

Comment: Also i release UAV before creating and using SRV

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this. Problem was in releasing. You can't access compute shader's resources until it is fully unbind and released.

**Edit** you dont have to release it at all. Only "unplug" UAV from from gpu.

```
//code is shortened
//create UAV
D3D->CreateTexture2D( &textureDesc, NULL, &pTexture );
D3DD->CreateUnorderedAccessView( pTexture, &viewDescUAV, &pTextureUAV );

D3DC->dispatch(...);

//pTextureUAV->release(); // You dont have to release (if you want to use UAV again)
outputTexH->SetUnorderedAccessView(NULL); // This is what is important

effpass->Apply(0,D3DC); // unbind compute shader

//create SRV on the texture, use it.
```